# Spark -- Return identity value from SQL Server from Spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I need to insert a row into a SQL table from Spark running on Azure Databricks and want to know if there is a way to return the identity value from the primary key that gets generated from SQL Server (@@IDENTITY) back to Databricks

Answer (score 1):

was able to capture scope_identity from sql